# watch command not showing colors for 'git status'

Tags: colors, git, watch

I'm trying to get `watch` to display colors from 'git status'.

I've tried running watch with the `--color` option, as suggested elsewhere here, but, still, `watch --color 'git status'` doesn't display colors.

Comment: Are you sure your version of `watch` supports `--color`?

Comment: related: [Prevent watch breaking colors](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41980/9537)

Comment: @jw013: Yes, it's in the options list.

Comment: Make sure colors are turned on for `git status`.  Note that `auto` is insufficient for `watch` since output is not to a terminal.  You'll have to `git config color.status always`, at least for running under `watch`.

Comment: Git’s `-c` option can be used to set a value for `color.status` for a single command: `git -c color.status=always status`

Comment: @jw013, setting `config.color.status` to `always` did the trick! If you just add that as an answer I'll mark it as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When `git status` is run under `watch`, it is able to detect that its standard output is not a terminal, meaning it will not output colors if the `color.status` setting is set to `auto`.  To force `git status` to always output colors (even under `watch`), set `color.stats` to `always`, e.g.

```
git config color.status always
```

to set the setting permanently, or as [@ChrisJonsen points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46814/watch-command-not-showing-colors-for-git-status/47065#comment65142_46814), use `git -c color.status=always status` to run `git status` with a one-time override.