# why does watch remove the colors from git log

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, git, watch

possible duplicate : [watch command not showing colors for 'git status'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46814/watch-command-not-showing-colors-for-git-status)

running the following command:
`watch -n1 git --no-pager log --oneline --graph -20`

reproduces what i expect only it strips colors. In the possible duplicate it says that git detects that `stdout` is not terminal and hence strips the colors but the solutions does not work for `git log` on my machine (`osx high sierra`, `zsh`)

note - the following code does give me the everything with colors - i'm just interested if `watch` can do it too:

```
while :
do
clear
date
git --no-pager log --one-line --graph --20 
sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than always forcing git to color, you can enable color for just one command with a flag:

```
git log --color
```

So your command would be:

```
watch --color -n1 git --no-pager log --color --oneline --graph -20
```

I'm not sure why the linked answer didn't work, but I hope this works better.